# I am trying to run Karma ODTs but I am unable to map paths for .json files

Tags: json, karma-runner, odt

Some of my spec files contain the reference to .json files like below but the actual path of the .json file is different

```
define([

    'Redux/Redux',
    ..,
    ..,
    'text!/XYZ/assets/state.json'
],
```

Actual Path is `/XYZ/somedir/src/assets/state.json`
So just how `.js` files can be mapped in `karma.conf.js` file, can JSON files be mapped the same way?